# gdal rasterizelayer fails

Tags: python, gdal, rasterization

I have been trying to rasterize a shapefile with polygons in it. At some point it worked but then something changed and I do not know what happened. In the code below (a bit messy, I apologize) I create a polygon of which I am sure it is within the raster that I also define. I then rasterize it but the result is a raster with just zeroes. I'm sure it is something small and stupid but I can not find it.

I have the proj4string in a function, you can find it [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/amersfoort-rd-new/ogcwkt/). Or run the following line before you run the code:

```
proj_string_rd_new = 'PROJCS["Amersfoort / RD New",GEOGCS["Amersfoort",DATUM["Amersfoort",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6289"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4289"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52.15616055555555],PARAMETER["central_meridian",5.38763888888889],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999079],PARAMETER["false_easting",155000],PARAMETER["false_northing",463000],AUTHORITY["EPSG","28992"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]'
```

This is the tidy(er) code

```
from osgeo import gdal,ogr
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# open the raster layer and get its relevant properties
bbox_labs = [115733,517588,115744,517594]
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = bbox_labs
tileGeoTransformationParams = (xmin,0.25,0,ymax,0,-0.25) 

#define a polygon which is certainly in the bounding box. 
ply_wkt = '''POLYGON ((115743.63541881 517592.2735109,115742.76797302 517591.189203662,115734.852530185 517591.622926557,115734.852530185 517592.381941624,115743.63541881 517592.2735109))'''
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(ply_wkt)

# Create the output Driver
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer('test.shp', geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon )
# Get the output Layer's Feature Definition
featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
# create a new feature
outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
# Set new geometry
outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
# Add new feature to output Layer
outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
# dereference the feature
outFeature = None
# Save and close DataSources
outDataSource = None

# This works so I know that I can excess the shapefile and the geometry
#i = 0
#for feature in outLayer:
#    print( feature.geometry())
#    break
#print(i)


# Create the destination data source
rasterDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
tempSource = rasterDriver.Create(fn_out_tiff, 
                                 int((xmax-xmin)*4), 
                                 int((ymax-ymin)*4),
                                 1, #missed parameter (band)
                                 gdal.GDT_Int16)

#tempSource.SetProjection(proj_string_rd_new)
tempTile = tempSource.GetRasterBand(1)
tempTile.Fill(0)
tempTile.SetNoDataValue(-9999)

# The commented lines are thing I tried but also did not work. 
gdal.RasterizeLayer(tempSource, 
                    [1], 
                    outLayer,
#                    None,None,
                    burn_values = [1],
#                    ['ATTRIBUTE=val',
                    options = ['ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE'])
                    #options=["ATTRIBUTE=val"])

band_array = tempSource.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
print(1 in band_array) # returns False. Should return True
```

Comment: I guess that you have a typo in this coordinate of your polygon: `17591.189203662`.

Comment: I had, but that was not the problem. This one creeped in while copying. I have tried it with several different polygons and with a feature of 950 polygons